# Downgrade Nexus 4 from Android 4.3 to 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, downgrade

I updated my Nexus 4 to Android 4.3. I don't like it, so I want to return to version 4.2.2. How do I go back to a previous version?

Comment: Am curious as to what was the reasoning behind the downgrade? Unstable, broken functionality, despite some claiming 4.3 was good? :)

Comment: One very valid reason for wanting to downgrade is that the [camera software is broken](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67113) in 4.3 and 4.4 and results in intermittent crashes and reboots. For whatever reason, Google shows no interest in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the official Factory Images from Google's [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam) page, and the download contains all that you need to downgrade. Unfortunately, this means you'll lose all data on the device, so be sure to make backups beforehand.

Basically, you'll have to download and extract the package, install drivers if necessary, boot your device into fastboot mode and use the script (`flash-all.sh` for Linux/Mac or `flash-all.bat` for Windows) from the package to flash the image. More detailed instructions can be found on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010312).