# Downgrade Nexus 4 from 4.4 to 4.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, factory-reset, 4.4-kitkat, downgrade

I have recently updated  my Nexus from 4.3 to 4.4 . But having an immediate requirement i would like to downgrade back to 4.2 . I originally bought it with 4.2.

Any step by step to downgrade back are highly recommended.
tried factory reset but of no luck. Is rooting mandatory for this? I have read some where that factory images are helpful. Please throw some light on this and a step by step document is needed being a layman on this?

Comment: Factory reset only removes "user data", it does nothing to system files. A factory image is probably your best option.

Comment: How do i proceed with a factory image? Where to get it from and how to install it in my device?

Comment: See: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). When you found your ROM, you most likely found the instructions along.

Comment: Do i need to root my device to proceed further? Is this the correct link i found as in screenshot.https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjigbqx7rygf8wr/Nexus%204%20factory%20images.JPG Where can i find Instructions for this after download? I may be missing those for my nexus looking for 4.2.2 in that link

Answer (score 1):

this might helps.
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50728/39466

Pretty much details process from XDA forums
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010312